# How to add custom local fonts to a Nextjs 13 Tailwind project?

Tags: next.js, fonts, tailwind-css

I have downloaded a couple fonts (NOT GOOGLE FONTS) and I want to add and use them in my Nextjs 13 Tailwind project.

I've followed the Nextjs docs to try add a single font (I want to add multiple fonts but trying to get a single font added isn't working):

1. npm install @next/font
2. Add the downloaded font files to `/pages/fonts`
3. Add the fonts to `/pages/_app.js`
4. Add the fonts to `tailwind.config.js`
5. Use font in a component

Updated /pages/_app.js

```
import localFont from '@next/font/local'

const surt = localFont({
  src: './fonts/Surt-Normal-Bold.woff2',
  variable: '--font-surt-bold',
})

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <main className={surt.variable}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </main>
  )
}
```

Updated tailwind.config.js (Surt is a sans-serif font)

```
const { fontFamily } = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['var(--font-surt)', ...fontFamily.sans],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Updated About page

```
export default function About() {
  return <div className="font-surt-bold">About</div>
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how would I update the code to add another font (eg Surt-Normal-Regular.woff2, Surt-Normal-Semibold-Italic.woff2)

Answer (score 49):

Full credit goes to [Lee Robinson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L8_98i_bMMA&ab_channel=LeeRobinson) and official [v13 doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/font-optimization) for my post.

The below will also help you with the new v13 `/app` directory.

### 1. Install next fonts

```
npm install @next/font
```

### 2. Download your fonts

In my case I downloaded the Poppins fonts and placed them in `/public/fonts/`

### 3. Link to your fonts file

As per `docs` you can edit your `_app.js`.

- Link to your local fonts
- assign a variable name
- assign the class name to a parent html tag

In my case I am using the new app directory: `/src/app/layout.tsx`

```js
import localFont from '@next/font/local'

const poppins = localFont({
  src: [
    {
      path: '../../public/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf',
      weight: '400'
    },
    {
      path: '../../public/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf',
      weight: '700'
    }
  ],
  variable: '--font-poppins'
})

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" className={`${poppins.variable} font-sans`}>
    ...
```

### 4. Reference in Tailwind config

As per [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/font-optimization#with-tailwind-css) you can now reference the new variable in your `tailwind.config.js`.

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}', // Note the addition of the `app` directory.
    './src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'
  ],
  theme: {
   
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['var(--font-poppins)']
      }
  
    }
  },
  plugins: []
}
```

Comment: Hi. do you have any idea how to do the same in a MUI project? I want to set font-family inside MUI global theme and also be able to use different styles of a single font-family.

Comment: is there any difference if i use otf file? right now i am converting to ttf to be safe side

Comment: `next/font` is included by default since Next.js 13, so you can import it without the `@` character - `import localFont from 'next/font/local'` - https://vercel.com/blog/nextjs-next-font

Comment: For me the "font-sans" class name was missing. Thanks for this!

Comment: What if you have multiple custom local fonts that you want to import? i.e a heading font that wouldn't be applied to <main>?

Answer (score 5):

If you `console.log(surt)`,

```
const surt = localFont({
  src: "../fonts/test.woff2",
  variable: "--font-test-bold",
});
console.log("surt", surt);
```

you get this

```
// I used different font so values might be different
surt {
  style: { fontFamily: "'__surt_899d56', '__surt_Fallback_899d56'" },
  className: '__className_899d56',
  variable: '__variable_899d56'
}
```

You dont need any configuration. All you have to do is apply this `surt.className` to an element and that font will be applied to all children.

```
 <main className={surt.className}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </main>
```

It works both for client components and `app` directory

- how to apply this to any component in the project

I did the above configuration in `_app.js` and I did use any className or variable

```
import localFont from "@next/font/local";

const surt = localFont({
  src: "../public/test.woff2",
  variable: "--font-surt",
  // I added this maybe fallback works but it did not
  fallback: ["'Apple Color Emoji'"],
});
console.log("surt", surt);
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <main>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </main>
  );
}
```

After you configure the tailwind.css the way you did, we should be able to use `font-sans` class anywhere in the project but no matter what I tried, tailwind does not inject it (it must be a bug). Workaround is like this. If you console the font, you will get this:

```
className: "__className_899d56"
style: {fontFamily: "'__surt_899d56', 'Apple Color Emoji','__surt_Fallback_899d56'"}
variable: "__variable_899d56"
```

I copied the `style` property from console (You could prop drill) and manually used it:

```
<p
    className="'__className_899d56'"
    style={{ fontFamily: "__surt_899d56" }}
  >
    with font testing
  </p>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! How would you add multiple fonts and use the font in a particular component.. not applying to all components

Answer (score 5):

After setting up TailwindCSS the way you did to use the font you should also add `font-sans` in the className you want to add the font to.

In this case, your `_app.js` should be

```js
import localFont from '@next/font/local'

const surt = localFont({
  src: './fonts/Surt-Normal-Bold.woff2',
  variable: '--font-surt-bold',
})

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <main className={`${surt.variable} font-sans`}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </main>
  )
}
```

If you want to have different variants of the same font you can pass an array to the font `src` instead.

You can do it this way

```js
const surt = localFont({
  src: [
    {
      path: "./fonts/Surt-Normal-Regular.woff2",
      weight: "400",
      style: "normal",
    },
    {
      path: "./fonts/Surt-Normal-Bold.woff2",
      weight: "700",
      style: "normal",
    },
    {
      path: "./fonts/Surt-Normal-Black.woff2",
      weight: "900",
      style: "normal",
    },
  ],
  variable: "--font-surt-bold",
});
```

it is mentioned in the docs [Here](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/optimizing/fonts#local-fonts)